# Get location of view on screen in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

To get the location/position of a view, it's pretty standard:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
childView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
```

However, if I'm on the 2nd of a `ViewPager`, and I try to get the location of a view on the screen, this calculation is off. On the 1st page of the ViewPager, it gives the correct location of 15 for the x-axis. However, on the 2nd page, it's giving 1095 for the x-axis. I noticed that it seems to be adding 1080 to the x value because the resolution of the device is 1080px in width. If I try to get the location of the same view on the 3rd page of the ViewPager, it gives 2175 (1080 + 1080 + 15).

So how can I get the location of a view on the screen without adding additional pixels because of the ViewPager?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `PagerAdapter` you may override the [`instantiateItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/PagerAdapter#instantiateItem(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)). You can receive **`int position`** as an argument.

So keep the `position` somewhere and later combine with View's width (`viewWidth`):

```
x = location[0] - viewWidth * position;
```

Comment: Is there no other way to get the position of the view on screen without having to add widths/multiply positions?